# Adding two NSMutableDictionaries in 1 NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary, ios7.1, fhs-twitter-engine

Here,I am trying to get both the followers and followings of `twitter` using
 `FHSTwitterEngine`. Here is my code to get followers and adding
 `dictionary` into `NSMutableArray` to print in a `tableView`.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict1 = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]listFollowersForUser:usernames isID:NO withCursor:@"-1"];
  NSLog(@"====> %@",[dict1 objectForKey:@"users"] );
 twttrFrndListVC.twitterFrndList=[dict1 objectForKey:@"users"];
```

Using above code,I can get followers. But when i try to get both
followers and followings,it doesn't work.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *dict1 = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]listFollowersForUser:username isID:NO withCursor:@"-1"];
 NSMutableDictionary *dict2 = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine] listFriendsForUser:username isID:NO withCursor:@"-1"];
      NSLog(@"====> %@",[dict1 objectForKey:@"users"] );
     twttrFrndListVC.twitterFrndList=[dict1 objectForKey:@"users"],[dict2 objectForKey:@"users"];
```

Above code returns followers name only. How can I get values of both
 dictionaries ? How can I add two `NSMutableDictionaries` in one
 `NSMutableArray` ? Both the dictionaries have same keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are only printing out dict1, that might lead to the assumption that you only get the followers back
2. I guess twttrFrndListVC.twitterFrndList is an NSArray.

To union different arrays together you want to use the following code:

```
NSArray *arr1 = [[NSArray alloc]init];
NSArray *arr2 = [[NSArray alloc]init];

NSArray *arr1ANDarr2 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:arr1];
arr1ANDarr2 = [arr1ANDarr2 arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:arr2];
```

In your specific case that would be:

```
twttrFrndListVC.twitterFrndList = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[dict1 objectForKey:@"users"]];
twttrFrndListVC.twitterFrndList = [twttrFrndListVC.twitterFrndList arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[dict2 objectForKey:@"users"]];
```

Unfortunately I cannot tell if your Twitter code is correct as I've never worked with that.
Hope that helps!

EDIT:
I just saw you are using an NSMutableArray, which adds an additional way to do this:

```
NSArray *arr1 = [[NSArray alloc]init];
NSArray *arr2 = [[NSArray alloc]init];

NSMutableArray *arr1ANDarr2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:arr1];
[arr1ANDarr2 addObjectsFromArray:arr2];
```

In your case:

```
twttrFrndListVC.twitterFrndList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[dict1 objectForKey:@"users"]];
[twttrFrndListVC.twitterFrndList addObjectsFromArray:[dict2 objectForKey:@"users"]]];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dear...Thankeww very @dfinki. You saved my hours.

Comment: your welcome. being able to help on a monday morning is a good start! @iDev